# Change item's data type in a List or array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-js

how can i change item's data type in arrays or lists in kotlin ?
i found a usual way but i need an easier and faster and better way to change data type of an array :)

```
fun typeChanger (data:MutableList<Number>): DoubleArray {
    val result = mutableListOf<Double>()
    for (i in data.iterator()){
        result.add(i.toDouble())
    }
    return result.toDoubleArray()
}
val x = mutableListOf<Number>(+1,+1,-1,-1)
val xx:DoubleArray = typeChanger(x) // It works but i need an easier and faster and better way :)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array `map` is your friend. You could keep your function and simplify, or remove it completely as below:-

```
val xx = x.map { it.toDouble() }
```

Once it's a list of doubles, you can then leave as a list or use `.toDoubleArray()` if you need an array.